# Can you install WebSphere Portal and WCM 8.5 without DB2?

Tags: ibm, websphere

I'm a Java developer trying to debug a production problem involving threads in a portlet on WebSphere Portal and WCM 8.5. In order to isolate the issue and not impact on other development, I need to set up a dev playground on a Windows 64-bit machine on a powerful laptop with lots of RAM.

I've downloaded and installed par numbers CIZ5PML, CIYV9ML, CIZ5QML, CIYW0ML, CIYW1ML, CIYW2ML as listed [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHRKX_8.5.0/mp/dd/dd_wcm.html).

No errors, all fine, but I basically end up with a single cw_profile WAS profile and nothing else. Naturally I was expecting to get an installed WCM console with a derby database backend I can start adding and registering portlets to.

I know there is [new a command line tool to create WebSphere Application Server profiles](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21442487) because the IBM GUI profile creation tool is busted on Windows 64-bits. It works fine for regular non-Network Deployment WebSphere installations, but do I need to use it here in this case ?

The only decent reference I have found for the following steps is [here](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/domino/OpenAttachment/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/05C3AA3F941E73B185257CF2005FD86C/attach/sbsPortal85Cluster.pdf) and [here](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/domino/OpenAttachment/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/CDBAB351B04DBA6685257D160049C31A/attach/sbsPortal85Cluster002.pdf) but they seem to require the installation of DB2 and stuff I don't need like the IBM HTTP Server and an LDAP Server.

I just want to get coding, what is the shortest path to get the WCM console up and running locally? Any enlightenment greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you ask IBM? Generally you get the whole kitchen sink with the IBM product downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally concluded the installation successfully. DB2 is not required. And no, you should not use the regular IBM WebSphere Application Server profile creation tool mentioned above for WCM.

What I had missed earlier was I needed to start the cw profile, then go to the configuration wizard at web page http://localhost:10200/ibm/wizard

Log in.

All the way at the bottom: More Options > Create the IBM WebSphere Portal Profile

Select a new profile name myprofile.

Then launch it and let it do its thing for about an hour.

After that I rebooted Windows.

AS AN ADMINISTRATOR I tried to launch the new profile's server from the Windows Start menu IBM WebSphere > IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5 > profiles > myprofile > Start the server

That didn't work because the shortcut was pointing to:

```
C:\IBM\WebSphere\myprofile\bin\startServer.bat server1
```

I changed it to:

```
C:\IBM\WebSphere\myprofile\bin\startServer.bat WebSphere_Portal
```

and started it successfully. I also launched the cw profile's server to be on the safe side.

Then I looked and looked for the correct URLs to the WAS admin console and the Portal console. The ports were not correctly indicated in the file
C:\IBM\WebSphere\myprofile\logs\AboutThisProfile.txt

but they were correctly indicated in file:
C:\IBM\WebSphere\myprofile\config\cells\MyComputerNameCell\nodes\MyComputerNameNode\serverindex.xml

The URL for my admin console turned out to be:
https://localhost:10061/ibm/console/logon.jsp

The URL for Web Content Manager turned out to be reachable at:
https://localhost:10062/wps/portal/

I hope this helps someone and now I can get started coding.